# New Object in JPQL and selects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

Why would a JPQL query

```
Select new Foo(X,Y) from X join X.y as Y Where ...
```

produces more than one sql? 1 for main select and 1 each for X and Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's guess. One query that selects that IDs of X, Y and then 1 query for X to load its other fields (in the constructor of Foo), and then 1 query for Y to load its other fields (when accessed in the constructor of Foo).

Obviously you could easily do

```
SELECT new Foo(x.id, x.field2, x.field3, y.id, y.field2) FROM X join X.y as Y ...
```

and that would (with DataNucleus JPA) do a single SELECT.